# How can I deploy Airflow on docker compose?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, airflow

I can find the docker-compose.yaml file from Apache official website [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html)

I am able to run airflow, the docker images are pulled the official images, everything works perfectly on my local machine.

However, my question is, how can I deploy airflow with docker-compose on a Cloud managed service? e.g. Azure App Service

I am using Azure, but it seems to me that Azure container registry won't work. I cannot push the docker image as I am not building any image.

Comment: I recommend using azure-cli.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose

Comment: Hmm you should be able to access docker files from docker hub though